# Adding http-only and secure property as true sets only secure attribute on cookie in spring boot

Tags: spring, security, tomcat, cookies, spring-boot

Setting following properties works on localhost but not on server

```
server.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.session.cookie.secure=true
```

On server the cookie is only set as secure not as HTTPOnly.

The application is built in spring boot with embedded tomcat.
The cookie on localhost is being set as

```
JSESSIONID  
value   "value"
path    "/"
secure  true
httpOnly    true
```

On server it is

```
JSESSIONID  
value   "value"
path    "/"
secure  true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Be more clear. What are you asking? What implies that the settings above don't work on your server? (Errors? Behavior?)

Comment: The cookies should be set as
JSESSIONID 
value "value"
path "/"
secure true
httpOnly true
However, it is being set as

JSESSIONID 
value "value"
path "/"
secure true

Comment: I have updated the desc in my question

Comment: What is difference local and server? Did they have same configuration properties? Are you connecting with https? Delete all domain cookies and try again, I think it's working.